How do you access values passed in jQuery post on the action page (in Coldfusion)?
I'm passing a couple of variables to a Coldfusion page using jQuery.post():
jQuery.post(
                "myPage.cfm",
                {type:thisType, recordId:thisID},...

On myPage.cfm, it tells me that neither "type" nor "recordId" are defined in the form scope, nor in the scope we normally use to hold both url and form variables. Since these were both passed as part of an object, how does one access them?

jQuery.post() sends them the same way the form inputs are sent, so you should be able to access them just as if you'd submitted a form with <input name="type"> and <input name="recordId">

How are you calling your passed items? #form.type# ?

I'd guess thisType and recordId are not defined. What happens if you hardcode the values? Try outputting the values to the console to check them before the post() function.

are you using contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json" in the jQuery.post ?

<cfdump var=“#VARIABLES#”> might help you determine the appropriate scope.

By default, if you use jQuery.post() with simple key-value pairs, they will be available in the FORM scope in ColdFusion.
